# How can I make Spring identify beans without using xml or annotations?

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations, javabeans

I'm trying to integrate Spring framework into an existing project that contains thousands of pojos.
Writing an xml configuration file or going through each file and annotating the classes will be a tough time-consuming task, so is there a way to make Spring scan packages and identify the beans based solely on name convention ?

Comment: What's wrong with using `<context:component-scan/>`?  That does what you need, it sounds like.

Comment: @skaffman: The problem is that i don't want to modify the existing code, so if i use that, i will have to annotate manually all the classes that i need to be wired by @component or one of its specialized annotations.

Comment: So how would you like to identify the beans?  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@Component`-scanning behaviour of `<context:component-scan>` is only the default. You can customize its behaviour using name-based filters. See [section 3.10.3 of the manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters) for an example:

```
<beans>

   <context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
      <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*Stub.*Repository"/>
      <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                              expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
   </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

So you can make it detect your beans by the naming convention of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd option is using the @Configuration and @Bean Annotations and using the [Java-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java). But then you are writing code to wire your dependencies together and create your beans.

Answer (score 0):

The first question you need to ask yourself is, is it really necessary to wire all those beans?   Out of all the objects in your system only a small subset really need to be wired:   those that are configurable and those that have dependencies on other wired beans.

Comment: you're right, but even if i try to narrow down the number by figure out what are the beans that need to be wired, the number will still be huge (i'm dealing with an enterprise application)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Bozho.

There is a workaround - you can define your own custom [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html), where you can put the logic for scanning through the classes in your existing project based on your naming conventions and registering the BeanDefinitions for the classes in your existing project.

Yes, this requires coding though and is not something that you get out of the box.